# symmetric random walk with the empirical mean of returning time goes to $\infty$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2 \cdots $ be a sequence of random variables, taking values $P[X_1 = 1] = \frac{1}{2} = P[X_1 = -1]$. Let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. Let $T_0 = 0$. Define $T_{k+1} = \inf\{n > T_k, S_n =  0\}$ for $k \geq 0$. $T_k$ means $k$th return to $0$. prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty}(T_k /k) = \infty$ a.s.

---

I just need to know if I can use the Central limit theorem to solve this. Is this the right direction?

Comment: You should just use the law of large numbers with $T_k$ being a sum of iid random variables.

Comment: To me it seems that $T_{k+1}$ depends on $T_k$, and how to express $T_k$ in an explicit formula?

Comment: Yes indeed, as you would expect when $T_k$ is a sum of iid random variables.

Comment: My basic idea is to use some recursive definition $T_0 = 0$, so $T_{k+1} = T_k + \mathbb{1}_{X_{T_{k+1}}} + \cdots$, but how to make it click?

Comment: Every time you return to state 0 is a renewal, what happens next is independent of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: consider $t = \min\{n: S_n = 0\}$. Try to show that $T_k \sim t_1 + \ldots + t_k$, where $t_i \sim t$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it.